# mysqli bind_param and affected rows error

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am new to mysqli, I have checked PHP Manual and so on, nothing works. I am not quite sure what went wrong. I keep receiving this error:

```
Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param() [mysqli-stmt.bind-param]: Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement in C:\xampp\htdocs\new1\template.php on line 165
```

and this

```
Warning: mysqli_stmt_affected_rows() [function.mysqli-stmt-affected-rows]: Couldn't fetch mysqli_stmt in C:\xampp\htdocs\new1\template.php on line 190
```

**Coding**

```
$query = "INSERT INTO pets (name, age, gender, dob, breed_type, breed1, breed2, color, spay, size, hair_length, vaccine, vaccinated, dewormed, adoption_fees, aboutpet, petpic1, petpic2, petpic3) VALUES ('?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?')";

// PREPARE QUERY TO BE EXECUTED.
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);

$stmt->bind_param("sssssssssssssssssss",$petname, $petage, $petgender, $petdob, $petbreedtype, $petbreed1, $petbreed2, $petcolor, $petspay, $petsize, $pethair, $petvaccine, $petvaccineamount, $petdewormed, $petadoptfees, $aboutpet, $target_path, $target_path1, $target_path2 );

$petname  = $_POST['petname'];
$petage   = $_POST['petage'];
$petgender = $_POST['petgender'];
$petdob = $_POST['petdob'];
$petbreedtype = $_POST['petbreedtype'];
$petbreed1 = $_POST['petbreed1'];
$petbreed2 = $_POST['petbreed2'];
$petcolor = $_POST['petcolor'];
$petspay = $_POST['petspay'];
$petsize = $_POST['petsize'];
$pethair = $_POST['pethair'];
$petvaccine = $_POST['petvaccine'];
$petvaccineamount = $_POST['petvaccineamount'];
$petdewormed = $_POST['petdewormed'];
$petadoptfees = $_POST['petadoptfees'];
$aboutpet = $_POST['aboutpet'];

//EXECUTE QUERY
$stmt->execute();

//CLOSE EXECUTE
$stmt->close();

$rowcount = mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt);
if ($rowcount > 0)
{
echo "<div class='noerror'>Form has been submitted successfully!</div>";
}
```

Please help, I am totally lost now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must not quote your `?` placeholders: doing so causes them to be parsed as string literals instead of placeholders.

Therefore:

```
$query = "
  INSERT INTO pets (
    name, age, gender, dob, breed_type, breed1, breed2, color, spay, size,
    hair_length, vaccine, vaccinated, dewormed, adoption_fees, aboutpet,
    petpic1, petpic2, petpic3
  ) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
";
```

Comment: Nice one.. Didn't think of that.

Comment: Means? Sorry I am new to mysqli, I tried google around for tutorial, very less result I found. Mind showing example?

Comment: You should remove the single quotes (') around the question marks ('?' -> ?).

Comment: Yeap it works now, but Warning: mysqli_stmt_affected_rows() [function.mysqli-stmt-affected-rows]: Couldn't fetch mysqli_stmt in C:\xampp\htdocs\new1\template.php on line 190 still exist

Comment: I tried, it gave me Warning: main() [function.main]: Property access is not allowed yet in C:\xampp\htdocs\new1\template.php on line 191

Comment: @user1631889: Aha!  You're closing the statement before fetching the number of affected rows.  Move `$stmt->close();` to later in the code.

Answer (score 0):

The number of '?'s doesn't match the number of variables you put in using bind_param.  You do the counting, but there is a discrepancy of some sort.

EDIT:
You should also use $_POST['param'] in your bind_param. And don't pump all those $_POST['variables'] in new ones.

EDIT2:
Read about [normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Answer (score 0):

First - your extract your $_POST variables after you reference them- you need to move then "$stmt->bind_param(" line down below the $_POST variables

Second - you don't need to put quotes around your '?' variables - if you do that it will treat them as strings instead of bind params

Comment: Your first point is incorrect.  See [Example #1](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php#example-1661) in the PHP manual page for `mysqli_stmt::bind_param()`.

Comment: Oh - We have a wrapper class around our PDO calls so I never noticed it worked that way.. Cool